# Partial View linkage to controller and model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I am new to .Net and MVC and I seem to hit a problem that I can´t fix. I am trying to follow a couple of tutorials but I have failed when it comes to partial views. I looked up a lot of answers here and on different websites and still nothing works. I can´t figure out what I am doing wrong.

This is my partial controller:

```
 public class PartialController : Controller
  {
    public ActionResult _PartialView()
    {
        var model = new Partial();
        model.Count = 2;

        return PartialView(model);
    }
  }
```

And this is my Partial View:

```
@model WebApplication1Tutorial.Models.Partial
<div>
The magic number is: 
@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Count) 
</div>
```

I call this view in Index.cshtml by the following command:

```
<div>
@Html.Partial("/Views/Partial/_PartView.cshtml",new Partial())
</div>
```

And finally this is the model:

```
public class Partial
{
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Everything that I tried comes up with the webpage displaying the text and the number 0. I really have no idea what else to do. I know it is something easy but I can´t see it.

Thanks for the help.

Edit. The code for the index view:

```
@model MovieGenreViewModel
@{
  ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
 }

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
 <a asp-action="Create">Create New</a>
</p>

<form asp-controller="Movies" asp-action="Index" method="get">
<p>
    <select asp-for="movieGenre" asp-items="Model.genres">
        <option value="">All</option>
    </select>

    Title: <input type="text" name="SearchString" >
    <input type="submit" value="Filter" />
</p>
</form>

<table class="table">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.movies[0].Genre)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.movies[0].Price)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.movies[0].ReleaseDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.movies[0].Title)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.movies[0].Rating)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach (var item in Model.movies) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReleaseDate)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Rating)
        </td>
        <td>
            <a asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Edit</a> |
            <a asp-action="Details" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Details</a> |
            <a asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@item.ID">Delete</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
}
</tbody>
</table>

<div>
@{ Html.RenderAction("_PartialView"); }
</div>
```

Comment: I saw that a lot of people were saying to us @Html.Action, the only problem i have is when I try it says that the model for index doesn't contain a definition for Action.

Comment: Thank you for identifying the issue and helping me solve it. sorry to have wasted your time.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass your partial like with the @Html.Partial, you also pass a new Model and the _PartialView() method is not invoked so the model is not populated with the value 2.
You could use @Html.Action helper:

```
<div>
    @Html.Action("/Views/Partial/_PartView.cshtml")
</div>
```